# How to call another variable inside ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Need your help:

```
//ts file
export class SettingsPage {
  pays: [string] = [];
  gateways: string = '';
```

I can successfully call both individually but when i call `gateways` inside `pays` loop it doesn't work:

```
<ion-row>

  <ion-item *ngFor="let pay of pays">
  <ion-icon name="image" item-start></ion-icon>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pay['payto']" placeholder="{{pay.name}}">
  {{gateways.desc}}   // doesn't work inside the loop
  </ion-input>

{{gateways.desc}} // works fine outside the loop

</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not being shown because it's not valid to add anything inside of the `ion-input` (check **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/)**).

You can definitely add that inside of the loop, like this:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let pay of pays">
    <ion-icon name="image" item-start></ion-icon>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pay['payto']" placeholder="{{pay.name}}"></ion-input>
    <ion-note item-end>{{ gateways.desc }}</ion-note>
  </ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

I'm using an `ion-note` just to add another *valid Ionic layout*, but you could add whatever you want if it's valid in Ionic.

Comment: That's correct. I was curious why i couldn't make it without tag if it was okay with `<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pay['payto']" placeholder="{{gateways[pay.name] || pay.name}}"></ion-input>`

Comment: Glad to help :) @user3449848

Answer (score 1):

seems like you have not closed `<ion-item *ngFor="let pay of pays">` tag

Try this hope it will work

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let pay of pays">
          <ion-icon name="image" item-start></ion-icon>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pay['payto']" placeholder="{{pay.name}}">
          {{gateways.desc}}   // doesn't work inside the loop
          </ion-input>
    </ion-item> <!-- close this  tag -->
    {{gateways.desc}} // works fine outside the loop

</ion-row>
```

Comment: I just forgot to add it here. I did it in my script otherwise output would return error.